# Submitting a URL to astrometry's API using fetch

Tags: typescript, fetch-api

I have a project in svelte kit and typescript. I have one uploadPhoto/+page.server.ts file containing:

```
import { ImgurClient } from 'imgur';
import type { PageServerLoad, Action, Actions } from './$types';
import { mssqlConnection } from '../../db/mssqldb';
import { Request } from 'mssql';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { fail, redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
let username: string;

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
    if (!locals.user) {
        throw redirect(302, 'login');
    } else {
        username = locals.user.username;

        if (process.env.NOVA_KEY) {
            const sessionKey = await fetchAstrometrySessionKey(process.env.NOVA_KEY);
            console.log(sessionKey);
            const data=await submitURL(sessionKey, 'https://i.imgur.com/Q5i9bmX.jpg');
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
};
const client = new ImgurClient({
    accessToken: process.env.TOKEN,
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
});

async function saveURL(url: string) {
    const connection = await mssqlConnection();
    const selectRequest = new Request(connection);
    const selectResult = await selectRequest
        .input('Username', username)
        .query('SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username');
    const id = selectResult.recordset[0].Id;
    console.log(id);
    const insertRequest = new Request(connection);
    const insertResult = await insertRequest
        .input('Id', uuidv4())
        .input('UserId', id)
        .input('ImageURL', url)
        .query('INSERT INTO UsersImages(Id, UserId, ImageURL) VALUES(@Id, @UserId, @ImageURL)');
    return insertResult === undefined;
}

async function uploadToUmgur(file: File) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(await file.arrayBuffer());
    const base64 = buffer.toString('base64');
    const response = await client.upload({
        image: base64,
        type: 'base64'
    });
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
}

async function fetchAstrometrySessionKey(apikey: string) {
    const response = await fetch('http://nova.astrometry.net/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: `request-json=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ apikey }))}`
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Could not obtain session key: ' + data.message);
    }
    return data.session;
}

async function submitURL(sessionId: string, url: string) {
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            session: sessionId,
            url: url,
            scale_units: 'degwidth',
            scale_lower: 0.5,
            scale_upper: 1.0,
            center_ra: 290,
            center_dec: 11,
            radius: 2.0
        })
    };
    console.log(options.body)

    const response = await fetch('http://nova.astrometry.net/api/url_upload', options);
    const result = await response.json();

    if (result.status === 'success') {
        console.log(`Successful submission: ${result.subid} with hash ${result.hash}`);
        return result.subid;
    } else {
        console.error(result);
        return null;
    }
}

const upload: Action = async ({ request }) => {
    try {
        if (request.method === 'POST') {
            const form = await request.formData();
            const image = form.get('img') as File;
            console.log(form.get('img'));
            if (image) {
                console.log(`Received file with name: ${image.name}`);
                const link = (await uploadToUmgur(image)).link;
                console.log(link);
                if (await saveURL(link)) {
                    return link;
                } else {
                    fail(500, { error: true });
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

export const actions: Actions = { upload };
```

Just for testing purpose I have called the fetchAstrometrySessionKey and submitURL. The fetchAstrometrySessionKey is working fine. However the submitURL is giving me errors. When I try to fetch this post request I get:

```
{ status: 'error', errormessage: 'no json' }
```

the console output is the following:

```
asjoissd9fdg0fijdgf
{
method: 'POST',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
body: '{"session":"7675zfa9ef8ddikpcplhx2akb42htcqo","url":"https://i.imgur.com/Q5i9bmX.jpg","scale_units":"degwidth","scale_lower":0.5,"scale_upper":1,"center_ra":290,"center_dec":11,"radius":2}'
}
{ status: 'error', errormessage: 'no json' }
```

the string of letters and numbers is the session (for security purpose this is not a valid session) Then I log the options variable. Last is the response

I have tried changing the application/x-www-form-urlencoded to application/json but this time I may get no json or terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://astrometry.net/doc/net/api.html#submitting-a-url), you need to send all JSON as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` via the `request-json` field.

Basically, use the same format as your *login* request

```js
// note, no extra headers required when using URLSearchParams
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    "request-json": JSON.stringify({
      session: sessionId,
      url: url,
      scale_units: 'degwidth',
      scale_lower: 0.5,
      scale_upper: 1.0,
      center_ra: 290,
      center_dec: 11,
      radius: 2.0
    })
  }
};

const response = await fetch('http://nova.astrometry.net/api/url_upload', options);
```